# Vector subscript out of range, error only shown in debug mode

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, outofrangeexception

Visual Studio Debug is showing the exception "Vector subscript out of range" (only debug mode) but I can't detect it. There's nothing wrong, it's selection sort algorithm.

Source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void ascending_sort(vector<T> & list) {
    size_t i, j, index;

    for (i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        index = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list[j] < list[index]) {
                index = j;
            }
        }

        if (index != i) {
            T item = list[i];

            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = item;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    vector<int> list = { 5, 1, -14, 8 };

    ascending_sort(list);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
5
-14
8
```

Answer (score 5):

In `ascending_sort()`,

```
if (index != i) {
    T item = list[i];

    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j] = item;
}
```

You should use `index` instead of `j`, which might be `list.size()` after the `for` loop, then `list[j]` will cause out of range issue. Change it to

```
if (index != i) {
    T item = list[i];

    list[i] = list[index];
    list[index] = item;
}
```

---

<sup>[`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) doesn't perform bounds checking, it leads to undefined behaviour when subscript is out of range. It seems VS will throw exception in DEBUG mode, but this is not guaranteed by the standard. You could use [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead, which will throw `std::out_of_range` when subscript is out of range.</sup>